# Content provider query construction and default table

Tags: java, android, sql

I have a content provider that includes a table, and I want to query a specific entry with the key value *"key1"*, so I did the following in the `query()` method of my content provider:

```
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        qb.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, null, null, null, sortOrder);
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
    }
```

How do I construct the `String selection` as the second argument? I tried to set the selection as *"key='key1'"* but failed.

I currently have a content provider, and have only 1 table in it. Is there any way to refer to the table directly via the `URI`? Now I have to use `URI/Table_name`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but possibly the extra quotes are the issue. Your selection string should something like *key="key1"* (or *key='key1'*).

Also, your provider can interpret the Uri in any way it wants, but the standard way is to use a UriMatcher and specify it with a table name (as you have with URI/Table_name).